# Buggy android does not turn on

Tags: cyanogenmod, 6.0-marshmallow, boot, reboot, micromax-yu-yuphoria

I got a Yu Yuphoria 5010. 
I had custom installed Marshmallow CyanogenMod a few months back.

Recently, the settings would not open. Instead it started showing the message:

```
Unfortunately, Settings has stopped

                   Report    Cancel
```

The bug report would also not get reported when I press `Report`. So I tried to reboot the system. Although the phone shut down. But it didn't turn on anymore. I tried charging the phone for a couple hours, but in vain. I cannot even enter the recovery mode by pressing `vol up + power + vol down` keys.

I tried browsing the net for possible solutions. The closest I came was this section *Did it gradually get buggy and then die?* on this [link](https://www.androidpit.com/why-won-t-my-phone-turn-on).

How can I restore my phone's functionality?

Comment: You should attempt to flash it. Does the computer detect it?

Comment: nope. my Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't detect it at all.

Comment: Which variant it is? Qualcomm or Mediatek?

Comment: it's Qualcomm, in both 5010 and 5010A. and mine is 5010.

Comment: The phone should be detected... I don't use Ubuntu... I think there should be a device manager like in Windows, watch what is displayed there when you connect the phone to the computer.

Comment: no, the thing is the phone is dead. It is not powering up at all.

Comment: Do what I am asking you to!!! Your phone should be detected even though it is not powering on!!

Comment: Preferably use a Windows computer! I've no experience with Ubuntu.

Comment: Search on Google Qualcomm drivers for your device and for Ubuntu... There are thousands of links on internet by for Windows only. Can't help much there.

Comment: the phone is not detected either in Ubuntu or Windows.

Comment: Did you install drivers (Windows) ?

Comment: It used to detect automatically when I connected my phone to Windows.

Comment: Yeah obviously it was working and MTP drivers are default installed​ on Windows computer. Now we need to get your device out of the dead, for this we need some special drivers! If you think you are not able to do that, just bring your​ phone to a repair shop.